# Java POI exception

Tags: java

These are the steps that i do:

Save excel file.
Run program that reads the excel file.

When i do those steps i get this error immediately:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecord(RecordFactory.java:224)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:160)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:163)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:130)
>    at
>
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   11  at
>   org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndian.getNumber(LittleEndian.java:491)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndian.getInt(LittleEndian.java:139)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.BOFRecord.fillFields(BOFRecord.java:133)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record.fillFields(Record.java:90)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record.(Record.java:55)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.BOFRecord.(BOFRecord.java:98)
>    ... 12 more
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException:
>   Unable to construct record instance,
>   the following exception occured: null
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecord(RecordFactory.java:237)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:160)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:163)
>    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:130)
>    at

When i do these steps i dont get the error:

Save excel file.

Open excel file.

Click on a cell.

Hit save.

Run program.

No error is thrown.

Does anyone know why this would be? It is very frustrating!!!!!

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess: You're missing the library it's trying to reflect upon? *shrug* The stack trace doesn't tell us much.

Comment: but why would it go away after i open the file and save it?

Comment: Maybe there's a compatibility/format issue?

Comment: yeah maybe it comes in as a newer excel file and when i save it i save it as an older one or something...

Comment: Sorry, but there really is no way to help you. You've provided no code, and have only described the steps you've taken to produce the error. What does your program look like? How are you executing it?

Answer (score 2):

1 of the scenario in poi 2.5.1 is,

If you select a data validation cell right before saving the excel document, you get the similar stack trace.
The workaround would be to select simple text cell then proceed to save the document.

bug report filed, https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50761

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of various reasons.

One I just found:

U will get this error, if excel has any filter enabled