# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when try to read excel sheet by using org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, spring, struct

i am getting the following exception when i try to read Excel sheet by using **org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook**

```
    C:\BuildAndDep\BI_Resource_List.xls
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecord(RecordFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:212)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:193)
    at com.emc.deployportal.util.CommUtil2.readExceSheet(CommUtil2.java:718)
    at com.emc.deployportal.util.CommUtil2.main(CommUtil2.java:739)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.UnknownRecord.<init>(UnknownRecord.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.SubRecord.createSubRecord(SubRecord.java:57)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.ObjRecord.fillFields(ObjRecord.java:99)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record.fillFields(Record.java:90)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record.<init>(Record.java:55)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.ObjRecord.<init>(ObjRecord.java:61)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: Unable to construct record instance, the following exception occured: null
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecord(RecordFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:212)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:193)
    at com.emc.deployportal.util.CommUtil2.readExceSheet(CommUtil2.java:718)
    at com.emc.deployportal.util.CommUtil2.main(CommUtil2.java:739)
```

My program is :

```
public static void readExceSheet() {
        String filePath = "C:\\BuildAndDep\\BI_Resource_List.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = null;
        int numberOfSheets;
        try {
            System.out.println(filePath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            numberOfSheets = workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
            System.out.println(numberOfSheets);
            if( 0 == numberOfSheets) {

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("================= file not found =================");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("================= exception ======================");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

when i ran this code, it throwing exception. any suggestion plz.

thanks

Comment: which version of jdk you are using ? try doing it with latest version

Comment: before getting number of sheets from workbook can you do this  HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("Sheet1");

Comment: Might this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188052/java-poi-exception